# jquery not loading in chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I'm trying to load a local jquery file into a chrome extension. this is what my manifest.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "TV",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Search",
  "icons": { "128": "icon.jpg" },
    "options_page": "options.html",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "TV",
    "default_icon": "icon.jpg",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://*.thetvdb.com/*", "tabs"
  ],
"content_scripts": [ {
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "*://jquery.com/*"],
    "js": [ "jquery.js", "options.js" ]
  }]
}
```

and the function in options.js:

```
function searchS(){
    console.log($)
}
```

and that returns me:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: what is `$`? try instead console.log('hello')

Comment: @sag - `$` is the default jQuery wrapper.  He is looking to get an output similar to this - `function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}` signaling that jQuery is available.

Comment: exactly, the hello won't output if jquery is working or not

Comment: If I add jquery using <script> on the options.html it works good, but shouldn't it work with the import in the manifest?!