# How to post / get data to another server in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-chrome-extension

So I have a google chrome extension that tracks some data and posts it to: Either a server on the web or a locally installed application on the user's machine; depending on the user's choice. So far the best way to do this *(so far, lemme know otherwise)* is to run AJAX's `post()` / `get()`. I noticed [w3schools's](https://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)  tutorials mentioned that jQuery is able to run AJAX's `post()` / `get()`;

I currently have [compressed jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js) `3.4.1` downloaded to `extension_root/thirdParty/jquery.min.js` and am attempting to load it via the `extensions_root/manifest.json` file:

```
...
"background": {
    "scripts": [
      "thirdParty/jquery.min.js",
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
},
...
```

In my `extensions_root/background.js` I've attempted to use `$` like the examples I've seen. *This is the first time I've ever used jQuery so am working based off of examples.* and anything using the `$()` breaks. **Error:**(Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function)

A sample I've tried: `$('p').innerHTML = 'jQuery working';`

Now I **did** notice that `jQuery` is defined, but I don't know how I use it, as `jQuery` in place of `$` also breaks. I noticed a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665324/jquery-not-loading-in-chrome-extension) and was inspired by one of the comments to check whether `jQuery.fn.init` was defined, *it was*; But I'm still stuck.

My problems I still have are that I:
 - A: Can't send data to a local server or a web server. (Due to B)
 - B: Can't find any way to load / use jQuery

Comment: The background script declaration crates a hidden and empty background page where that script runs so usually there's no sense in creating elements inside. Looks like you're mistakenly trying to use the script also elsewhere.

Comment: I have no desire to create / load / get elements. I saw via https://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp that is was possible to use jQuery for `get` / `post`.

Comment: Since I don't see what exactly you're doing I can only guess based on the information in the question. The posted fragment of manifest is correct and it should work provided you reloaded the extension after changing the manifest which you can do on chrome://extensions page by clicking the reload icon on the extension card.

Comment: My first paragraph explains what my end goal is. I decided jQuery was the best method for me to use. 

I've reloaded my extension via the icon already and completely un-installed / re-install my extension already.

Comment: There's a limit to what I can guess so I can't help further without seeing the entire extension. The behavior you've described so far is typical for misusing the background script in another place like the popup or the content script.

Comment: BTW you don't need jQuery to make the requests. Simply use the built-in `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`, there are tons of examples.

Comment: Oh?! I never took the time to learn how to make requests to another server before today. (I've only ever made client side apps) I just assumed jQuery was a requirement since I saw it mentioned everywhere when I started researching.

Thanks, I'll look into those two.